# Why does it show two days consecutive when I have visited more consecutive days?

Tags: support

[image]

Why does it show only two days consecutive? I have visited regularly from 2nd to 18th right?

Comment: Yep 24th and 25th are two consecutive days from the last gap. Consecutive is - most recent consecutive days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just takes into account the latest consecutive visits, which is from 24<sup>th</sup> to 25<sup>th</sup>, which is 2 days only. It's not a max of all consecutive visits.

Answer (score 0):

From the dictionary definition of [*consecutive*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/consecutive):

> 1. following one another in uninterrupted succession or order; successive: six consecutive numbers, such as 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Only the most recent series of consecutive days is counted; you only visited the last two days consecutively; days before the last break do not count, because they were not consecutive.

Only days you were active *during the UTC day* count; where *active* means more than just logging in and looking at your profile. The exact activities that count are not disclosed but it is easy enough to maintain a daily 'presence'.

Comment: Oh, I always thought logging was enough... It might explains my 2 separates days break in the last 8 months which break my consecutive days so :-)